# Prove that $0$-$1$ $\mathsf{ Ineq}$ is $\mathsf{NL}$-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, reductions, space-complexity

I need to prove that the following problem $0$-$1$ $\mathsf{ Ineq}$ is $\mathsf{NL}$-complete.

Given a finite set of variables $V$, a finite set of inequalities of the form $x \le y$ (where $x, y \in V$) and a finite set of equalities of the form $x=a$ (where $x \in V$ and $a \in \{0,1\}$), is there an assignment of values from $\{0, 1\}$ to the variables satisfying all the inequalities and all the equalities?

How can I start to resolve the proof?

Comment: A start: what are the two things you need to show when you want to prove something is NL-complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Directed reachability is NL-complete.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is 2SAT in disguise.